# Silverlight: Listening to changes in control's TranslateTransform

Tags: animation, silverlight-4.0, transform

Given that I have the following transform:

```
transform = control.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
```

How can I get a notification when its property's X value changes?

I'm using a control which automatically does some animations using a TranslateTransform. What I would like to do is to "listen" to these changes and to get a notification automatically when the TranslateTransform's X-property changes.

My first solution was to create a thread which polls the current value. This works but it isn't extremely beautiful solution. Then I had the idea of using DependencyPropertyListener to listen to the transform's X-value. But for some reason this doesn't seem to work. The changed event is never executed even though through polling I see that the value is changing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Using the DependencyPropertyListener with TranslateTransform didn't work for some reason. I'm planning to revisit this problem in near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you incorporate the PropertyObserver pattern. You can then setup an event handler basically and be notified whenever the value changes.

Look here: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/